# HTML5 Canvas - How to bounce two circles?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, animation, canvas

I have created and array of full circle objects (lets call it a ball object) using html5 canvas arc

```
c.arc(circle.x, circle.y, circle.r, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
```

Balls are moving with in the canvas area only. If they hit the edge they will bounce (change their direction velocity and speed). Now that was quite simple to implement. I add or substract the radius to the balls center (curent canvas X and Y position) based on the direction it moves in.

```
// controll ball velocity
function controlBallVelocityOnBoundHit(circle){
    if(circle.x + circle.vx + circle.r > container.x + container.w || circle.x - circle.r + circle.vx < container.x){
      circle.vx = -circle.vx;
      controlSlowingDownAndDirectionBallsAfterBounce(circle);
    }
    if(circle.y + circle.vy + circle.r > container.y + container.h || circle.y - circle.r + circle.vy < container.y){
      circle.vy = -circle.vy;
      controlSlowingDownAndDirectionBallsAfterBounce(circle);
    }    
}
```

But now I would like to make them balls bounce of each other as soon as they touches at any point of their circumference.

How can I check if the canvas area is shared by two ball objects, or if one balls area is touching another balls area.

Here is the sample project on [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/GlupiJas/pen/QNrQPb?editors=1010). At the moment balls are moving one through another which is not the result I what to achive.

PROBLEM:
[image]
EXAMPLE: [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/GlupiJas/pen/QNrQPb?editors=1010)

Comment: There are numerous tutorials on this topic exactly. I would suggest some extensive googling of you haven't done so already. Try looking up n-body collisions. And javascript circle collision. There is a decent amount of physics involved, but I'm sure you can just copy the code

Comment: Ye i found the answer at Mozilla website: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Techniques/2D_collision_detection with example http://jsfiddle.net/gQ3hD/2/. Thx